# Exception thrown at 0x011414CE in chars.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004

Tags: c, pointers, memory, doubly-linked-list

So I'm wring a code for a program using C  that just performs basic linked list tasks like create the list, insert a node after a given current node, remove node , etc.

I am using visual studio 2015, so when I tried to test my insert-a-node-after function by debugging it and using visual studio watch to visualize my list and whether or not it was inserting nodes after the current node properly, I got the error:

Exception thrown at 0x011414CE in chars.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

Unhandled exception at 0x011414CE in chars.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

So here is my .h file with the struct and list declaration

```
#ifndef DLIST_H
#define DLIST_H


typedef struct DListNode_struct {
char *str;
int blankIndex;
int blankLength;
struct DListNode_struct *next;
struct DListNode_struct *prev;
} DListNode;

typedef struct DList_struct {
   int size;
   DListNode *head;
   DListNode *tail;
} DList;


void DListConstruct(DList* list);

void DListInsertAfter(DList* list, DListNode* currNode, DListNode* newNode);

#endif // DLIST_H
```

so here is my main function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dlist.h"

int main() {

DList* list = NULL;
DListNode* currNode = NULL;

DListNode* newNode1 = (DListNode*)malloc(sizeof(DListNode));

DListInsertAfter(list, currNode, newNode1);



return 0;
}
```

And here is my .c file where I have my insertafter function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dlist.h"


void DListConstruct(DList* list) {

list->head = NULL;
list->tail = NULL;
list->size = 0;

}



void DListInsertAfter(DList* list, DListNode* currNode, DListNode* newNode) {

DListNode* sucNode;

if (list->head == NULL) {
    list->head = newNode;
    list->tail = newNode;
}

else if (currNode == list->tail) {
    list->tail->next = newNode;
    newNode->prev = list->tail;
    list->tail = newNode;
}

else {
    sucNode = currNode->next;
    newNode->next = sucNode;
    newNode->prev = currNode;
    currNode->next = newNode;
    sucNode->prev = newNode;
}
}
```

I found some posts related to my question but all of them either do not target linked lists or are not in C.

So can anyone help me finding where the bug is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The debugger should tell you exactly which line of code is triggering the seg fault. Please provide that as a minimum. It's worth your time to learn to use the debugger more effectively.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing `NULL` to `DListInsertAfter` as `list` and first check `(list->head == NULL)` fails as you access null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Dlist after is receiving a list which is NULL
So going `list->head` is the problem. Since it doesn't exist!

You need to allocate the list first.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dlist.h"

int main() {

DList* list = NULL;
DListNode* currNode = NULL;

DListNode* newNode1 = (DListNode*)malloc(sizeof(DListNode));

DList* list = (void*)malloc(sizeof(DList));

DListInsertAfter(list, currNode, newNode1);



return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you tried to bold a line of code in Markdown; you can't do that, so it now looks like you're a bit trigger happy with the asterisks haha...

Comment: Ooops
I was in a rush to answer his question
But it seems some other people answered before I did :D

Answer (score 0):

the arrow operator `->` is syntactic sugar for dereference combined with struct member access. Therefore the line

```
if (list->head == NULL) {
```

is the same as

```
if ((*list).head == NULL) {
```

When you call `DListInsertAfter()` you pass in a pointer for the `list` parameter which is initialised to `NULL`. Therefore you are dereferencing a `NULL` pointer, which is probably causing your crash. You need at some point to allocate memory for your `DList` struct before you try to access it.